# "undefined method" for a rails model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Devise with rails and i want to add a method "getAllComments", so i write this :

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :city, :newsletter_register, :birthday, :postal_code,
          :address_complement, :address, :lastname, :firstname, :civility

      has_many :hotels_comments

      class << self # Class methods
          def getAllComments
             true
          end
      end
    end
```

And in my controller :

```
def dashboard
  @user = current_user
  @comments = @user.getAllComments();
end
```

And when i go to my url, i got

```
 undefined method `getAllComments' for #<User:0x00000008759718>
```

What i am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `getAllComments` is a class method and you are attempting to access it as an instance method.

You either need to access it as:

```
User.getAllComments
```

or redefine it as an instance method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...

  def getAllComments
    true
  end
end

def dashboard
  @user = current_user
  @comments = @user.getAllComments
end
```

Comment: Yes but i still has the same problem. I have to put a public before getAllComments maybe?

Comment: No. It is a public method my default. The exact code I posted will work, unless there is something else going on.

Comment: maybe you have 'protected' or 'private' above 'getAllComments' definition?

Comment: I deleted the public notation and it still works good. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you make getAllComments as class method through addition it to eigenclass. And you try to call this method from instance.

Answer (score 0):

Content of `class << self` means class method. It could be shortened as `def self.getAllComments`

You should call it `User.getAllComments` and not `@user.getAllComments`

Answer (score 0):

The getAllComments() method that you wrote is a class method

So the correct way to call the methods is

```
@comments = User.getAllComments
```

But if you really want to scope the getAllComments to the current user, I recommend you write an instance method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  def getAllComments
    // comments implementation
  end
```

So that way you can access the getAllComments method like so:

```
 @user = current_user
 @comments = @user.getAllComments
```